# Visual Studio Assertion Failed on C++ set comparator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, set, assertion

my code are having some problems on my Visual Studio 2010 but not on DevCPP. Heres the situation, I used C++ STL `set` in my code to insert `pair<string, double>` but then I want my `set` to sort them using the value instead of the key, so I used a custom comparator to achieve this.

```
struct sortPairSecond
{
   bool operator()(const pair<string, double> &lhs, const pair<string, double> &rhs)
   {
    return lhs.second >= rhs.second;
   }
};
```

The code works fine in DevCPP but encountered the Debug Assertion Failed on the xtree using VS2010. I did some debugging and I realize the error is caused by the use of >= in the custom comparator, eliminating the = make the code works but incorrect results as duplicate value should be allowed in my program. Therefore anyone can help me on this matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your using `>=` and not `>` may be invalid because it needs to be a strict ordering thus `op(a,b)` and `op(b,a)` cannot both be true (but they would be if they were equal).

It is just an assertion error but a `set` cannot contain duplicate values. Just use a sorted `vector` or you can use `multiset` (and use '>')

Of course as we know the first values are unique, we can extend the predicate when the second value is equal to compare the first. That will guarantee you unique values and then you can still use `std::set`.

```
struct sortPairSecond
{
   bool operator()(const pair<string, double> &lhs, const pair<string, double> &rhs) const
   {
    return (lhs.second > rhs.second) || (lhs.second == rhs.second && lhs.first > rhs.first) ;
   }
};
```

Essentially, don't try to "break" what `std::set` is intended to be used for by trying to manipulate your predicate.

Comment: Absolutely, >= is not allowed, should be >. But note that even in a `std::multiset` you should use >.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Now my code works and I have realize my initial mistake. Anyway, do you have any ideas why the code runs well on DevCPP but not on VS2010?

Comment: DevCPP is not checking the assertion and just attempts to sort, which in some ways is "undefined" behaviour as to what it produces. VS2010 would do the same on a release build.

Comment: @CashCow Forgive me but I have one follow-up question. The same exact code compiled using DevCPP takes about 20s to finish execution but if compiled using VS2010, it takes around 120s. Is it due to the "undefined" behavior or there are other reasons?

Comment: That's a long time in both cases, your data set must be very large. What optimisation settings are you using? Did you fix the predicate?

Comment: Yes its a very large data set. Well in order to better compare those two compilers, I use the exact same code for both of them. As in I omit the "=" in my original code so both compilers are using > instead of >=. Although it is not my intended results but I just do it for running time comparison purpose.