# Why this sort() will change value of the vector?

Tags: c++11

I was trying to solve this problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/board-cutting

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#define LL long long
#define M 1000000007LL
using namespace std;

int T,n,m;
LL cc;

struct Cut{
    int dir;
    LL cost;
    Cut(const int& dir, const LL& cost): dir(dir), cost(cost){}
    Cut(){}

    bool operator<(const Cut& cut) const
    {   
        return this->cost >= cut.cost;
    } 
};

vector<Cut> c;

int main() {
    cin >> T;
    while(T--){
        cin >> n >> m;
        LL ans = 0, cnt[2] = {0};
        c.clear();

        for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++) cin >> cc, c.push_back(Cut(0, cc));
        for(int i=0; i<m-1;i++) cin >> cc, c.push_back(Cut(1, cc));


        sort(c.begin(), c.end());


        for(int i=0; i<c.size(); i++){
            cout << c[i].cost << endl;
        }
        cout << "END" << endl;

        for(Cut x : c){
            (ans += x.cost*(1+cnt[!x.dir]))%=M;
            cnt[x.dir]++;
        }

        cout << ans << endl;   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have such a C++ code which consumes input from std I/O

I have added a loop to output the vector objects' cost property.
Now for the following input:

```
2
83 99
24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34
99 49
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61
```

The second test case does not have cost with 24 (only the first test case has 24)
But if you run the code, you will find that the vector contains Cut object with cost 24 after sort()!

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

**(The above sample input is hackerrank official test case input for this problem, so its correctness is assured)**

Comment: You should describe your problems somewhat better. Maybe try with simpler test set? Use a debugger to verify input and output. What IS input, what output?

Comment: @JeffRSon has edited to include problem link, I've try to cut down n, m, but cannot reproduce the same problem :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator>` has something very very wrong:

```
bool operator<(const Cut& cut) const
{   
    return this->cost >= cut.cost;
}
```

**If two elements are equals, it returns `true`** whereas it should return `false` !

Try that and you'll find peace (although the reverse logic still seems strange to me, maybe it makes sense in this situation, I didn't read the problem statement):

```
bool operator<(const Cut& cut) const
{   
    return this->cost > cut.cost;
}
```

Another thing that I find strange is that you stop your loop at `m-1` and `n-1`. Don't you want to read `m` and `n` values ?

Comment: Thanks! For m-1/ n-1 value, please read the problem statement :)
And can you explain why >= is wrong? Even I try to swap two values when they are equal, it is not stable but why it will change the value of the vector?

Comment: @shole That's not how it works. `sort` is written for correctly written comparers. If you tell it work with a badly written comparer, one that does not meet the requirements of the standard (including that an item is never less than or greater than itself), there's no safety net, there's no guarantee you get back your original items in some unspecified order.

Comment: @hvd It's still confusing me, but less confusing than before now...thanks. (I normally just skip all const, & in online contest, sometime it works sometimes it doesn't, still do not know why)

Comment: see here for some more explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375885/visual-studio-assertion-failed-on-c-set-comparator